# JsonBuilder not found with provided dependency javax javaee-api 8

Tags: java, json, maven, jboss, dependencies

Environment:

- Jboss 7.2
- java 11
- maven

I am trying to add the class javax.json.bind.JsonBuilder but when it compiles it says it cannot find symbol.

On Jboss 7.2 modules directory there is a jar javax.json.bind-api-1.0.0.redhat-1.jar that contains JsonBuilder.java.

Any idea where the problem is?

**Error**

```
Ping.java:[3,23] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class JsonBuilder
[ERROR]   location: package javax.json.bind
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax</groupId>
   <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
   <version>8.0</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Where is that error coming from? It does not look like it's coming from JBoss EAP.

Comment: mvn compile command

Comment: Did you define the `javax.json:javax.json-api` as a dependency as well?

Comment: No, I don't have this dependency javax.json:javax.json-api on pom.xml

Comment: You need to add the dependency too. I'm not too familiar with the `javax:javaee-api` dependency. Typically though if it's a BOM you'd use `<scope>import</scope>` and add a dependency to `javax.json:javax.json-api` to your POM too.